# How to open Compressed HTML file (.chm) in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, chm

Is there a way to view .chm files in Eclipse in an embedded manner?

Comment: Do you mean as help or to edit the HTML files?

Comment: I need to be able to open chm files to use as helper docs when developing code

Comment: On Windows, you can double-click the `.chm` file, e.g. in Windows Explorer, to display it in the Windows help viewer outside of Eclipse. On Linux you have to install `chmsee` for that, see e. g. https://askubuntu.com/q/8205/721289

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot open `.chm` files with Eclipse. But you can use **[7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) to extract** the content of a `.chm` file and then open the extracted HTML files in Eclipse.

To convert a `.chm` to an Eclipse help plug-in, an [Eclipse-specific `toc.xml` file](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_help_toc.html) from the corresponding SGML file contained in the `.chm` file has to be created. An Eclipse help plug-in requires also a simple `plugin.xml` and a `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file. The HTML files can be taken over unchanged.

Comment: Is there a tutorial available to convert a .chm to an Eclipse help plug-in? I have never written a plug-in before and don't really know where ti start.

Comment: As far as I know, there are only tutorials to create Eclipse plug-in from scratch, not from a `.chm` file, e. g. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCPHelpSystem/article.html